# Why is the value of the Image property of the PictureBox element null?

Tags: c#

I have the next class:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace course_project
{
    internal class Pike<T> : Fish
    {
        Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Green);
        public PictureBox aquarium = new AquariumForm().aquarium_picturebox;

        public Pike(T data) {
            Data = data;

            Draw((int[])(object)data);
        }

        public T Data { get; set; }

        public Pike<T> Next { get; set; }

        protected override void Draw(int[] coordinates)
        {
            Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(aquarium.Image);

            graphics.FillEllipse(brush, coordinates[0], coordinates[1], 40, 40);

            aquarium.Refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

Linked List:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace course_project
{
    internal class PikeFlock<T> : IEnumerable<T>
    {
        Pike<T> head;
        Pike<T> tail;
        int count;

        public void Add(T data)
        {
            Pike<T> pike = new Pike<T>(data);

            if (head == null)
                head = pike;
            else
                tail.Next = pike;
            tail = pike;

            count++;
        }

        public bool Remove(T data)
        {
            Pike<T> current = head;
            Pike<T> previous = null;

            while (current != null)
            {
                if (current.Data.Equals(data))
                {
                    if (previous != null)
                    {
                        previous.Next = current.Next;

                        if (current.Next == null)
                        {
                            tail = previous;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        head = head.Next;

                        if (head == null)
                            tail = null;
                    }
                    count--;
                    return true;
                }

                previous = current;
                current = current.Next;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public int Count { get { return count; } }

        public bool isEmpty { get { return count == 0; } }

        public void Clear()
        {
            head = null;
            tail = null;
            count = 0;
        }

        public bool Contains(T data)
        {
            Pike<T> current = head;
            while (current != null)
            {
                if (current.Data.Equals(data))
                    return true;
                current = current.Next;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public void AppendFirst(T data)
        {
            Pike<T> pike = new Pike<T>(data);
            pike.Next = head;
            head = pike;
            if (count == 0)
            {
                tail = head;
            }
            count++;
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return ((IEnumerable)this).GetEnumerator();
        }

        IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
        {
            Pike<T> current = head;
            while (current != null)
            {
                yield return current.Data;
                current = current.Next;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Button click event:

```
    private void add_pike_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PikeFlock<int[]> pikeFlock = new PikeFlock<int[]>();
        int[] coords = { 1, 2 };
        pikeFlock.Add(coords);
    }
```

Form1_Load:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(aquarium_picturebox.Width, aquarium_picturebox.Height);
        Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);

        graphics.Clear(Color.Blue);

        aquarium_picturebox.Image = bitmap;
        aquarium_picturebox.Refresh();
    }
```

But when you click the button an ArgumentNullException (System.ArgumentNullException: "The value cannot be undefined.
Parameter name: image".) is thrown because the Image property of the PictureBox element is empty for some reason.

How can it be solved? Please don't throw tomatoes, I just started to learn C# :)

Comment: Why do you assume that the picturebox.Image is assigned? Did you put an image in there?

Comment: `Draw((int[])(object)data);` if you know data is an int array why use generics?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Because when the form is loaded through the event Form_Load, the same PictureBox is normally filled with blue color

Comment: A PictureBox *filled with blue color* doesn't means has been assigned an Image. Also:  `public PictureBox aquarium = new AquariumForm().aquarium_picturebox;`? `new AquariumForm()`?

Comment: A PictureBox can display 3 (!) layers: A BackgrounfImage, an Image and things you draw onto its surface. Where is the code that load the Image?

Comment: @TaW The code of the Form1_Load event is attached to the question, where the image (color) is loaded into the PictureBox, and the code that draws on it is in the first attached code

Comment: ... and this: `public PictureBox aquarium = new AquariumForm().aquarium_picturebox;` is a new Form that exposes (wrongly) a PictureBox control that has no Image set yet. Maybe, if you move that code to the **Constructor** of the Form... (and possibly avoid to set the Access Modifier of a Control to something different than `private`, using a public Method or Property to get the reference of an Image - since you don't need the PictureBox at all).

Comment: Also, why are you creating a new instance of a Form, that you never show, just to get a bitmap? Do you think you'll change the Image of an existing instance of `AquariumForm`?